# MobX. Изменение поля объекта, являющегося элементом массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Мне нужно в MobX-сторе изменять поле у элемента массива.
`remove` работает, `makeDone` отрабатывает, но, похоже, компонент не узнаёт про изменения = если сделать `makeDone`, изменений не видно, если потом ещё сделать `remove`, изменение появляется (т.е. `makeDone` тот видно). Я пробовал и массив в `observable` обернуть, и объекты. Там, кстати, в комментах есть код, который работает - т.е. компонент сразу узнает про изменения, но мне показалось это странное решение, элемент удаляется и новый вставляется. Как правильно изменять поля у объекта, который является элементом массива ?

Файл **App.js**:

```js
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { todosStore } from './TodosStore';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

const App = observer(() => {
  const items = todosStore.items;
  return items.map((todo, index) => {
    const edit = (text) => todosStore.edit(index, text);
    const remove = () => todosStore.remove(index);
    const done = () => todosStore.makeDone(index);
    const actionProps = { edit, remove, done };
    return (
      <TodoItem item={todo} {...actionProps} />
    );
  })
});

export default App;
```

Файл **TodosStore.js**:

```js
import { observable, makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';

class TodosStore {
  todos = [
    { text: 'Learn CSS', done: false },
    { text: 'Learn JS', done: true },
    { text: 'Learn React', done: false },
    { text: 'Learn Mobx', done: false },
  ]

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  remove = (itemIndex) => {
    this.todos.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  }

  // how to mutate object in array ?
  makeDone = (itemIndex) => {
    const { done } = this.todos[itemIndex];
    this.todos[itemIndex].done = !done;
    // ^ that code doesn't works
    // let item = this.todos[itemIndex];
    // item.done = !done;
    // this.todos.splice(itemIndex, 1, item);
  }

  edit = (itemIndex, itemText) => {
    let item = this.todos[itemIndex];
    item.text = itemText;
    this.todos.splice(itemIndex, 1, item);
  }

  get items() {
    return this.todos;
  }
}

export const todosStore = new TodosStore();
```

Comment: Массив это тот же объект и передается по ссылке. Ссылка не меняется, а изменение элементов не равно изменению объекта. Единственный способ, это создавать новый массив в методе makeDone. После изменения массива сделайте так: `this.todos = [ ...this.todos ];`

Comment: @SwaD но тогда почему работает splice на массиве ? И даже с push я пробовал, работает, хотя ссылка 100% такая же.

Comment: Тебе нужно с шашечками или ехать? Обновляй ссылки. Как на массив, так и на объект - тогда все изменения будут "видны".

Comment: Мне нужно всего-лишь понимание, как такие задачи на MobX делать "православно". Т.е какой способ лучше. Я могу для изменения элемента массива сделать splice, т.е удалить и тут же вставить изменённый. Могу копировать весь массив. Вопрос в том, что более принято делать в таких случаях.

Comment: Еще заметил, попробуйте в методе makeDone, после изменения массива вернуть что нибудь, хоть `return this.todos`, метод splice возвращает удаленные элементы. А вот на счет православтя в MobX не подскажу

Comment: `this.todos = [ ...this.todos ];` вот это работает и ещё вот это(похожая логика)  `this.todos[itemIndex] = { ...this.todos[itemIndex] };`

Comment: Изменение ссылок будет работать всегда и везде. Остальное "от лукавого". Т.е. не глубокие изменения могут и отслеживаться. Т.ч. новые ссылки это и есть "православие" в действии.

Comment: В общем смешно вышло. В компоненте TodoItem не обернул всё в observer(). А с observer работает и не нужно никаких копий массивов / объектов делать.